# Pass user claims to downstream (secondary) APIs?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I have tried searching, but surprisingly cannot find an answer to my question.

I am designing a web app, that will have a front end interface via Angular, with multiple down stream APIs. Like below:

```
 [API - A Client] -> [API - A] -> [API - B]
```

I am using IdentityServer4 for authentication / authorization. Some users will have a particular claim, lets call it "Foo," and that claim gets correctly passed from the auth server to API A (using Implicit flow) when interacting with API A via the SPA client.

However, I can't get that claim to be passed along from API A to API B, which is using Client Credentials. From what I have read / research, this seems to be correct behavior, since its Client Credential flow.

So my question is, how can I pass a User claim ("Foo"), downstream to a second layer API (API-B)? do i need to use a different flow? Should API-A manually pass it along the request to API-B?

This is my first time using IdentityServer / OpenID connect / OAuth, I am open to changes.

**IdentityServer4 Config**

```
public class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("API-B", "API B")
            {
                UserClaims = { "Foo" }
            },
            new ApiResource("API-A", "API A")
            {
                ApiSecrets = {new Secret("Secret") },
                UserClaims = { "Foo",  },
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientName = "API-A Client",
                ClientId = "API-A_client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,

                RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:7900/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:7900/" },

                RequireConsent = false,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>(){
                    "API-A",
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                }
            },

            new Client
            {
                ClientName = "API-A Backend",
                ClientId = "API-A_backend",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

                ClientSecrets = {new Secret("Secret".Sha256()) },

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>()
                {
                    "API-B",
                    "custom_resource",
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                },
                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResource("custom_resource", new [] { "Foo" }),
        };
    }
}
```

**API A Auth Config**

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:6900";
                options.ApiName = "API-A";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // dev only!
            });
services.AddTransient<AccessTokenDelegatingHandler>((service) => new AccessTokenDelegatingHandler(tokenEndpoint: $"http://localhost:6900/connect/token", clientId: "API-A", clientSecret: "Secret", scope: "API-B"));

        services.AddHttpClient<ApiBHttpClient>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["ApiBUri"]);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        })
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<AccessTokenDelegatingHandler>();
```

**API B Auth Config**

```
    services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:6900";
                options.ApiName = "API-B"; // required audience of access tokens
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // dev only!
                options.ApiSecret = "Secret";
            });
```

The result above is API-A correctly gets access to "Foo" via IdentityClaims, however API-B does not (although the call is successful).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Finally found this GitHub page, asking the same question: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1679

Which leads here, about extension grants, http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html which is my exact scenario.

Comment: Link no longer exists.

Comment: Working link for extension grants: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html